# Visual Studio & Visual Studio Code, "Go To Definition" does not works for a third party javascript modules with index.d.ts file

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, node-modules

When I use a third party module I'm not able to go to definition in source code because IDE (Visual Studio & Code) go to declaration instead.

Example:

```
import { UserManager } from 'oidc-client';

export class AuthorizeService {

    constructor(){
        this.userManager = new UserManager();
    }

    async getUser() {
        const user = await this.userManager.getUser();
        return user;
    }
}
```

If you type **F12** on `getUser()` member, Visual Studio & Code, jumps to `index.d.ts` file instead of the source file that contains definitions.

TypeScript 2.9 has [--declarationMap](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#new---declarationmap) feature that enable linking between index.d.ts and source code, but this is available only on compile time.
So, only the author of the module can correct this behavior?